# Remove git submodule/repo inside repo fatal: Pathspec 'xfile.md' is in submodule 'x'

Tags: git, git-submodules

I accidentally create a repo around another repo.
I now just want the inner repo to just become part of the outer repo (I don't want a submodule/multi repos).

I went into the inner repo a removed the `.git` folder, but running `git status` doesn't show any changes and if I try and explicitly `git add` a file from the inner repo I get:

```
fatal: Pathspec 'xfile.md' is in submodule 'x'
```

I tried to reinit git from the outer repo but no luck.

I simply want to remove in the inner repo and make it become part of the parent repo. Had a google and a stack overflow search but answers seemed to get in depth pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you did not use [`git submodule deinit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309), the manual step would involve:

```
git rm --cached inner_repo
rm -f .git/modules/inner_repo
# edit .gitmodules
```

Replace '`inner_repo`' by the root folder name of your inner repo.
Don't add a trailing '`/`' at the end of `inner_repo`.
And edit the `.gitmodules` to remove the section which has `inner_repo` in it.